# char to char* issues

Tags: c++

i am able to covert char to char* using below function

```
char* char_to_chars(char ch) {
    char ch2[10];
    ch2[0] = ch;
    char *ch3 = &ch2[0];
    return ch3;
}
```

and i am calling above function here it gives what i want but still there some problem and i don't know what's wrong with it

```
char *ch2=char_to_chars(ch);
```

but when i write `cout<<ch2;` it prints address

and when i write `cout<<*ch2;` it prints character that has been converted

i want to do like when i write `cout<<ch2` it should print character that has been converted

what should i need change in my function or somewhere else

**UPDATE**

i am doing concatenation using this code.

```
char*lval = "bhavik";
char* concat(const char *nval) {
    int len = strlen(lval) + strlen(nval) + 1;
    char *temp = lval;
    lval = (char*) malloc(len * sizeof (char));
    strcpy(lval, temp);
    strcat(lval, nval);
    return lval;
}
```

is this good ?

Comment: Returning a pointer to a non-static local variable is pointless because dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: i am not able to understand what you saying

Comment: There are a couple problems with the `char_to_chars()` method you gave us; returning a reference to a stack-allocated array, creating an array that is far too big, and using `&ch2[0]` instead of `(char*)ch`. The function just doesn't look right...

Comment: Use `std::string` and call it a day.

Comment: @BhavikPatel In that case, I suggest you read [a good book about C++](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks) to help you grasp pointers and other basic concepts of C++.

Comment: What is the purpose of converting a `char` to a `char*`?

Comment: because i need to concat to char*

Comment: @BhavikPatel If I understand correctly, you want to concat the `char` on the end of an existing `char*`. Is that correct?

Comment: yes @MonadNewb that's why i am trying to convert it into char*

Comment: Your updated code is probably broken. What did `lval` originally point to? If it was dynamically allocated you've just lost that pointer and leaked memory. I suggest you read a good C++ book and use `std::string` instead of this flaky code.

Comment: You need to do some studying -- simply asking questions here will not do the job.

Comment: think lval is already defined, i did not mentioned where lval was declared ok that was mistake

Comment: @Blastfurnace and i am not able to use std::string in header file don't know why

Comment: @BhavikPatel you probably want to fix that then, that's by far the better solution.

Comment: If you still have trouble with the code in your "update" here, please post a new question asking about the specific problems you need help with there.

Comment: p.s. If this is a homework problem, I strongly doubt that using `strcat()` is allowed since it basically does all the work for you and makes your `concat()` function pretty much unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you initialize the `ch2` array in the stack (as a local variable).  When the function returns, the stack frame is cleaned, which "deletes" your array (in reality the stack frame is cleaned off, and is used in other function calls and local variables, gets overwritten with other values, so the pointer you return will point to junk).  You need to malloc the array in heap.

This way uses the heap:

```
char* char_to_chars(char ch) {
    char *ch2 = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    ch2[0] = ch;
    return ch2;
}
```

If you want to concatenate two `char*`'s, you can use the builtin `strcat` and `strncat` functions.  Just watch out that you have enough memory allocated.

Comment: done using your code,this is what i actually wanted

Comment: Why the -1?  How can I improve my post?

Comment: Considering the OP comment on concatenation, I don't think this really solves his problem.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour but this solved my problem

Comment: @BhavikPatel Actually Monad's answer is a much better answer. This answer also does not assure `ch2` is null terminated.

Comment: @BhavikPatel: Does this solve your problem? Now you have a resource management problem. You have to call `free()` to release this allocated memory at some point.

Comment: +1 since I don't think a -1 as score is justified for this answer.

Comment: @Layne So this is a C++ question yet the answer uses `malloc` on top of that it creates what is essentially a C style string that is not guaranteed to be `NULL` terminated and as Monad's answer shows memory allocation is not needed to solve this problem. So this answer is wrong on many levels.

Answer (score 3):

After discussion in the comments to the OP, it seems that you are asking about the wrong problem. From what I understand, you want to concat the `char` on the end of an existing `char*`.  If the `char*` points to a null-terminated string (commonly called a C-string), then you should simply copy the `char` to the end of the existing C-string and move the `NULL` character to the location just after the added `char`. Be sure that you actually have allocated enough memory to the `char*` so that you can leagally do this.

Comment: +1 for actually understanding the root issue.

Comment: ok let's go more inside see my updated question

Answer (score 2):

When you run `cout<<ch2;` you aren't outputting the value it is pointing to, you are outputting the address of that value in memory.  It is not possible for you to print out the value being pointed to without dereferencing the pointer by running `cout << *ch2;`

There are also a few tips I want to share with you.  Firstly, I would highly recommend giving your variables better names than `ch1`, `ch2`, `ch3`, etc.  That's just sloppy and it doesn't scale at all.  Secondly, your function does a lot of unnecessary actions.  Try doing it this way:

```
char* char_to_chars(char ch) {
char* convertedChar = new char;
*convertedChar = ch;
return convertedChar;
}
```

This creates a new pointer and allocates space on the heap to store a value. This is a much clearer and efficient way to convert a char into a pointer.  However, you could also do it without a function:

```
char* somePointer = &yourCharToConvert;
```

But long story short, if you are trying to output the value stored in the pointer just by typing `cout<<ch2;`, thats not gonna work